# Move silverlight application in dom?

Tags: javascript, html, silverlight, dom

Is it possible to move a node containing a silverlight application without silverlight application restart?

Comment: What are the results of testing? Does the element simply get a new parent in the DOM or is it temporarily removed from the DOM?

Comment: I made a final couple of tests and it doesn't work either way. Also noticed that it sometimes restarts when you change positioning to/from absolute. Gets a bit tricky when you would like to continue in another place after a click... start absolute, reposition/resize.

Comment: @simon you should answer your own question and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a final couple of tests and it doesn't work either way. Also noticed that the silverlight app sometimes restarts when you change positioning to/from absolute.

(This was some time ago so I should point out that never version might act different)